# Parsing words from text file using multithreading using C

Tags: c, multithreading

Currently I am attempting to parse words from all text files in a directory (in this case it is safe to assume there will only be text files within the directory). It seems as though I am able to open the file within the threads function, however I am unable to grab the text within. No error messages are being presented but the printf within `splitInput` is not printing to the terminal.

Forgive my semantic work within the code, I am a fresh novice with C! Along with this there may be unused code within main as this will be part of a larger project. I appreciate the assistance in advance!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "queue.h"

void* splitInput(void *filename) {

  printf("Thread %s Created\n", (char*)filename);

  FILE *file;

  int i = 0;
  char *cp;
  char *bp;
  char line[255];
  char *array[5000];

  file = fopen((char*)filename, "r");

  if(file == NULL) {
    perror("Error opening file");
  }



  printf("Opened File %s\n", (char*)filename);

  while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL) {

    bp = line;

    while(1) {

      cp = strtok(bp, ",.!? \n");
      bp = NULL;

      if(cp == NULL) {
        break;
      }

      array[i++] = cp;

      printf("Check print - word %i:%s:\n", i-1, cp);

    }
  }

  fclose(file);

  return 0;
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  DIR* d;

  struct dirent* e;

  // grab our queueSize and threadCount
  int queueSize = atoi(argv[2]);
  int threadCount = atoi(argv[3]);

  // var for creating a thread each file
  int i = 0;

  // open the dir
  d = opendir(argv[1]);

  printf("Queue Size: %d\n", queueSize);

  printf("Thread Count: %d\n", threadCount);

  // set our thread count now that we know how many files are in dir
  pthread_t threads[threadCount];


  // read through our directory
  while((e = readdir(d)) != NULL) {

    // make sure we aren't reading . and ..
    if(strcmp(e->d_name, ".") == 0) {
      continue;
    }

    if(strcmp(e->d_name, "..") == 0) {
      continue;
    }

    printf("entered file %s\n", e->d_name);

    char *filename = strdup(e->d_name);

    if(i < threadCount) {

      // create our threads
      pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, splitInput, filename);
    }

    // increment i
    i++;
  }

  // join our existing threads
  for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    pthread_join(threads[j], NULL);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Current Output

```
device@user:~/os/testdir$ ./output ~/os/testdir/test 10 10 output
Queue Size: 10
Thread Count: 10
entered file test
Thread test Created
Opened File test
```

Comment: `strtok` is not thread safe.  I haven't looked closely at your code, but in general "multi-threaded" and "strtok" do not go together.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, I was attempting to open a file outside my working directory which cannot be done without the full path. Changing the working directory to the parameter given solved the issue. This can be done in this case with `chdir(argv[1])`

Revised code below.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "queue.h"

void* splitInput(void *filename) {

  printf("Thread %s Created\n", (char*)filename);

  FILE *file;

  int i = 0;
  char *cp;
  char *bp;
  char line[255];
  char *array[5000];

  file = fopen((char*)filename, "r");

  if(file == NULL) {
    perror("Error opening file");
  }



  printf("Opened File %s\n", (char*)filename);

  while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL) {

    bp = line;

    while(1) {

      cp = strtok(bp, ",.!? \n");
      bp = NULL;

      if(cp == NULL) {
        break;
      }

      array[i++] = cp;

      printf("Check print - word %i:%s:\n", i-1, cp);

    }
  }

  fclose(file);

  return 0;
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  DIR* d;

  struct dirent* e;

  // grab our queueSize and threadCount
  int queueSize = atoi(argv[2]);
  int threadCount = atoi(argv[3]);

  // var for creating a thread each file
  int i = 0;

  // open the dir
  chdir(argv[1]);
  d = opendir(argv[1]);

  printf("Queue Size: %d\n", queueSize);

  printf("Thread Count: %d\n", threadCount);

  // set our thread count now that we know how many files are in dir
  pthread_t threads[threadCount];


  // read through our directory
  while((e = readdir(d)) != NULL) {

    // make sure we aren't reading . and ..
    if(strcmp(e->d_name, ".") == 0) {
      continue;
    }

    if(strcmp(e->d_name, "..") == 0) {
      continue;
    }

    printf("entered file %s\n", e->d_name);

    char *filename = strdup(e->d_name);

    if(i < threadCount) {

      // create our threads
      pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, splitInput, filename);
    }

    // increment i
    i++;
  }

  // join our existing threads
  for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    pthread_join(threads[j], NULL);
  }

  return 0;
}
```